# Associativity in C

Tags: c, operator-precedence

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a=10,b=20,c=30,d=40;
    
    
    if(a<=b == d>c)
    {
        printf("true");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("false");
    }
}
```

For the above code will the associativity come in picture as <= and > operators have same precedence.
So can i say that (Left to right) <= will be evaluated first and then > will be evaluated in this case

Comment: Why not just write `if( (a<=b) == (d>c) )` and get done with it?

Comment: ^^^^^^^^ who cares about associativity and checking precedence tables when you can explicitly define what you want?   I swear that some users, (or their profs), are actually allergic to brackets:)

Comment: Ahh -- indeterminately sequenced. (thank you)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operator precedence/associativity specifies which operators that "glue together" with which operand. In this case they specify that the expression should be parsed as `(a<=b) == (d>c)` and not `a<= (b==d) >c` etc.

Since the relational operators have higher precedence than equality operators, associativity doesn't matter here. It would only matter in case you had written something like `a <= b > c`.

Furthermore, don't mix up operator precedence with order of evaluation. In this case either the `a<=b` expression or the `d>c` expression might be evaluated first, since the `==` operator doesn't specify an order of evaluation of its operands. It's unspecified behavior and might differ from case to case.

For details see [What is the difference between operator precedence and order of evaluation?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/278172)

Comment: So like , int z =x++ + ++x; even in this case we are not sure about the order of execution..whether x++ will be executed first or ++x..it is totally on to the compiler to select which executes first???

Comment: In the case of code like 'int z =x++ + ++x;', the compiler should simply catch fire in an attempt to kill the user who wrote the code.

Comment: @narayanrathod That particular example would be the #1 C FAQ of all time. It's a bad example because it's simply undefined behavior and you can't know anything about it. See [Why can't we mix increment operators like i++ with other operators?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/278384)

Comment: @narayanrathod: The problem with that example is that invokes undefined behavior.  A better example would be something like `x = f() + g();` - there’s no guarantee that `f()` gets called before `g()` or vice versa.  The only operators that force left-to-right evaluation are the `&&`, `||`, `?:`, and comma operators (which is not the same as the comma that separates function arguments).